# Greenlight V3 Get Bigbluebutton MeetingId

Tags: reactjs, bigbluebutton

I am try to edit Greenlight V3
I want to get the MeetingId(BigBlueButton MeetingId) instead of the FriendlyId
I try to edit RoomCard.jsx bu I can not receive Meeting_id in this jsx.

When user copy the room link
I want to show url like below

[www.aaaa.com?meetinId=4546asdasdsdffse](http://www.aaaa.com?meetinId=4546asdasdsdffse)

Answer (score 0):

better to post in bigbluebutton-greenlight google forum your code you are trying to get help..  not enough information here to be able to help..